# Mouse click and drag Event WPF

Tags: wpf, events, click, drag

I am developing an analog clock picker control. 
The user is able to click on the minute or hour hand and drag to turn the needle to select the specific time. I was wondering how to detect such a click and drag event.

I tried using MouseLeftButtonDown + MouseMove but I cannot get it to work as MouseMove is always trigger when the mousemove happen despite me using a flag. Is there any easier way?

```
public bool dragAction = false;

private void minuteHand_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    dragAction = true;
    minuteHand_MouseMove(this.minuteHand, e);
}

private void minuteHand_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dragAction == true)
    {
       //my code: moving the needle
    }
 }

 private void minuteHand_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    dragAction = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 9):

I think this is the easiest and most straightforward way :

```
 private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
     if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) {
        this.DragMove();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public bool dragAction = false;

private void minuteHand_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    dragAction = true;
    minuteHand_MouseMove(this.minuteHand, e);
}

private void minuteHand_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dragAction == true)
    {
       this.DragMove();
    }
 }

 private void minuteHand_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    dragAction = false;
 }
```

does the trick

Comment: Isn't this just the same as the original post?

Comment: Original was missing: this.DragMove() function

Answer (score 4):

You can make things easier and need not handle mouse down / up :

```
private void minuteHand_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        //my code: moving the needle
    }
 }
```

Comment: I want the user to click and drag rather than just moving the mouse.

Comment: In wpf drag&Drop, use always PreviewMouseDown. That way you will achieve it working it with MouseMove. (MousDown is bubbling and not suitable for drag&drop)