# Is it possible to click drag a button image in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a Toolbar with buttons that have images just above their text. I want users to click the button and then drag. That should drag the image as long as the mouse button is held down. This should also work for touch screens (fingers).

I've been trying to use the code from this answer [Mouse click and drag Event WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441672/mouse-click-and-drag-event-wpf). But it doesn't seem to do anything. I end up dragging the entire form.

Any suggestions on how I can start this or if it is even possible?

Comment: There is already drag and drop events in WPF but I don't know how it works with a touch device